# How does flutter determine when to rebuild widgets?

Tags: flutter, build, widget, element

Have a look at the following code snippet.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final child = CustomTextWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: child, //CustomTextWidget(),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {});
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTextWidget() {
    print("constructed");
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("got built");
    return Text("click me");
  }
}
```

I can understand why in the following code the constructor and the build method of `CustomTextWidget` will be called with every build. It's because I'm giving a new object every time.

```dart
 RaisedButton(
    child: CustomTextWidget(),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {});
      }
  ),
```

but why is it that if I give it `child` the build method of the `CustomTextWidget` object does not get called with every build? The constructor is called one time which makes sense and then the build method just a single time. Why isn't build called with every `setState`?

```dart
 RaisedButton(
    child: child,
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {});
      }
  ),
```

How does flutter decide when to call these build methods?

Comment: It would be great if someone can provide a link to a detailed explanation of flutter build algorithm

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that you store your child in a State, which is attached to an Element, not a Widget. Widgets are always rebuilt, these classes are basically just what we - the programmers - see, they are rebuilt every time a parent calls setstate or a depended inherited widget changes, then these widgets are associated with elements by class name and/or Keys, and the elements represent what the frameworks actually will render. That's a good way to imagine it in your mind when you are programming.

Comment: You can read more on the internet: https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/inside-flutter https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d https://jelenaaa.medium.com/what-exactly-is-that-buildcontext-you-keep-seeing-in-your-build-methods-2ea729bea88d https://priscy.medium.com/how-flutter-renders-widgets-in-more-details-than-youll-need-742f4d359ad

Answer (score 1):

In this example

```
 RaisedButton(
    child: child,
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {});
      }
  ),
```

`build` wasn't called because the object didn't change. Flutter must be using the equality operator `==` to determine if a widget/object changed when `setState` is called. If the value is `false` build is not called. This is true in stateful, and stateless widgets. So the take away here is to always use `const` when possible, and declare your widgets outside the rebuild context when you don't want them to rebuilt.

Keep in mind that with `StatefulWidget`s there is another concept about when the `State` object held by the Element tree gets recreated in that regard Flutter looks at the type of the `StatefulWidget` as well as the `key` to determine if the `State` object should be recreated.

I hope this will help somebody out there.

Cheers