# Rebuild widget after using setState in flutter

Tags: flutter

In this below image, it is divided into 2 parts:

1. Textfield to create tags
2. Some data fetched from api and shown in grid view

Both are working fine but what I need is when I click on any of the boxes in grid view I want that same data to apper in above textfield.

I am using a package called **textfield_tags** for creating tags (textfield)

```
TextFieldTags(
  textfieldTagsController: _controller,
  initialTags: _skillsLists,
  textSeparators: const [' ', ','],
  letterCase: LetterCase.normal,
  validator: (String tag) {
  if (tag.length < 3) {
    return 'Tag cannot be smaller than 3 characters';
  } else if (_controller.getTags!.contains(tag)) {
    return 'Tag already exists';
  }
},
```

The above is code for the textfield tags, and there is a field named initialTags in above code and there is a list called **_skillsLists** which is initialized at top like this:

```
 List<String> _skillsLists = ['Figma'];
```

and in my below line I have created a grid view where if any of those boxes are clicked the data of the boxes are added to the list.

**For example if I click on HTML from girdview it is added to the list but it doesn't appear in above textfield as tags, it is just added to the list. What should I do? setState doen't help here.**

```
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _data.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Containers(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _skillsLists.add(_data[index].name);
          });
          print(_skillsLists);
        },
        width: size.width,
        color: Colors.pink,
        height: 30,
        child: Texts(texts: _data[index].name),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

`initialTags` is immutable in the `textfield_tags` package. As such, when you change the value of `_skillsLists`, the `TextFieldTags` widget doesn't actually change, and isn't rebuilt (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65178691/how-does-flutter-determine-when-to-rebuild-widgets) for a short explanation or search around a bit).

If you dig around a bit in the `textfield_tags` package, there is a function called `addTag` that will notify listeners and update `TextFieldTags`. So instead of using `setState`, use `addTag` like so:

```
GridView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: _data.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Containers(
        onTap: () {
          _controller.addTag = _data[index].name; // updated 
        },
        width: size.width,
        color: Colors.pink,
        height: 30,
        child: Texts(texts: _data[index].name),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

And if you want to retrieve the tags, the controller has a function `getTags` that returns `List<String>`.

Take a look at the controller's functions [here](https://github.com/eyoeldefare/textfield_tags/blob/master/lib/src/controller.dart) on the github repository of `textfield_tags`

Comment: I did exactly like u said above but it says "The method 'addTag' isn't defined for the type 'TextfieldTagsController'."

Comment: That's my bad, `.addTag` is a set function so you just use `=`, like so: `_controller.addTag = _data[index].name`. Here's [an example](https://github.com/eyoeldefare/textfield_tags/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart#L130) the package provides